# Rerun missing command with apt-get

Tags: command-line, apt

When I run a command on a new machine (or install that I'm testing) I often find that the package needs to be installed first. This leads, for example, to the following sequence:

```
> colordiff

The program 'colordiff' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install colordiff
```

Argggh.

```
> apt-get install colordiff
```

Is there a way, when given the prompt that says the command `You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install XXXX` to run `sudo apt-get install XXXX` without typing the entire line out? The best I can do is:

```
> apt-get install !!
```

but since *some* command (the shell?) is telling me what I should run, it would be nice if I could get that same program to run it for me.

Comment: Just do an arrow up, home. And type "sudo "?

Comment: @falconer Thanks for the link. It absolutely is a copy. I'm voting to close it myself, should I delete it as well or should I leave it up to help it to be linked to the better answer?

Comment: @Hooked Just leave it as it is. Will be closed soon. No need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of people that make an alias for `sudo apt-get install`. Something like `alias agi='sudo apt-get install'` in their `.bashrc` file.